# Ошибка CS0029: "Неявное преобразование типа невозможно" в C# в LINQ

Tags: c#

Встретился с ошибкой CS0029 в LINQовском коде. Код писал не я, но моя задача его доработать. Выдает ошибку "error CS0029: Неявное преобразование типа 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' в 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#2>' невозможно" на фрагменте кода:

```
 grouped =
  from r in result
  group r by new
  {
   r.KindOfCalculationsNumber,
   r.KindOfCalculationsCode,
   r.PeriodFor,
   r.SnuType,
   r.SnuName,
   r.IsAssist,
   r.DDS,
   r.DDP,
   r.PRC,
   r.KFTType,
   r.WRK,
   r.NUMERATOR,
   r.DENOMINATOR,
   r.FOVTYPE,
   r.RATEVALUE,
   r.INDFCT,
   r.KFTKV,
   r.OsnNote,
   r.TransferDate,
   r.ExcludeFromItog,
   r.ExcludeFromItogInter,
   r.SnuTypeCode,
   r.TransferType
  }
   into g
   let k = g.Key
   orderby k.SnuTypeCode, k.KindOfCalculationsNumber, k.PeriodFor, g.Min(t => t.SnuNumber)
   select new
   {
    k.KindOfCalculationsNumber,
    k.KindOfCalculationsCode,
    k.PeriodFor,
    k.SnuType,
    k.SnuTypeCode,
    SnuNumber = g.Min(t => t.SnuNumber),
    k.SnuName,
    k.IsAssist,
    k.DDS,
    k.DDP,
    k.PRC,
    k.KFTType,
    k.WRK,
    k.NUMERATOR,
    k.DENOMINATOR,
    k.FOVTYPE,
    k.RATEVALUE,
    k.INDFCT,
    k.KFTKV,
    k.OsnNote,
    TaxDeduction = g.Sum(t => t.TaxDeduction),
    TransferSum = g.Sum(t => t.TransferSum),
    k.TransferDate,
    k.ExcludeFromItog,
    k.ExcludeFromItogInter,
    Sum = g.Sum(t => t.Sum)
```

Жалуется на строку select new. Подскажите пожалуйста, что требуется исправить, или хотя бы с чего начать? Полный компилиремый CS-файл можно взять по ссылке https://disk.yandex.ru/d/S3AGUWMciF_HFQ

Comment: Ну собственно, вы объявили переменную grouped с типом `IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>` где-то выше, а тут вы пытаетесь записать в нее значение типа `IEnumerable<AnonymousType#2>`. Это невозможно. Заведите другую переменную.

Comment: Иными словами, чтобы проблема исчезла grouped в процитированном коде должна содержать то же количество тех же полей, какие были в момент ее определения? Новую переменную заводить нельзя, нужна эта. Это ясно из полного кода процедуры

Comment: да, либо набор полей одинаковый, тогда не будет AnonymousType#2, будет только AnonymousType#1 всегда

Comment: @АндрейNOP, спасибо, я хотел бы пометить Ваш ответ как ответ на мой вопрос. Насколько я понял, я не могу этого сделать сейчас поскольку Вы не запостили свой коммент как ответ, а просто как коммент. Вы не могли бы запостить свой ответ как ответ?

Comment: Вы можете написать ответ самостоятельно, мне лень это делать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выяснено: при объявлении этой переменной grouped с типом IEnumerable в нем был другой набор полей, чем в приведенном мною примере в момент присвоения этой переменной значения. Чтобы проблема исчезла, grouped в процитированном коде должна содержать то же количество тех же полей, какие были в момент ее определения